# Border in MapFish Print 3

Tags: printing, geoserver, mapfish

I am using MapFish Print. How can I add a border for Map block. I have not found this in the [documentation](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/extensions/printing/index.html). I want to add a border like in this [image: picture]

I will be glad to any hint